# Do I create a repository in GitHub Desktop FIRST or on GitHub FIRST?

Tags: github, github-desktop

I have files for a website in a folder on my computer that I'd like to put on GitHub. Do I create a repository in GitHub Desktop first or create a repository on GitHub first? And once I have a repository what is the very first thing I do to move those files into the repository? This may be a stupid question but I've made a mess of things and I'm very confused at this point.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Create a repository on GitHub](https://github.com/new)
2. `git clone` your new repository on your computer
3. Copy the files you want to push to your repository inside the new folder created by cloning
4. `git add --all` to add all these files for commit
5. `git commit -m "Initial commit"` to create a commit
6. `git push` to push this commit to your GitHub repository